# Disk caching http Library for Java: Does it exist?

Tags: java, http, caching, etag

Apache HttpClient does not have caching as far as I can see so my question is do you know about a Http library that can cache to disk? It would be fun to implement it myself but before i do it, it is better to check if it already exists :-)

Requirements:
Support for Http 1.1
Can cache to disk (ex: a folder)
Support for a maximum cache size on disk
Support for eTag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[HTTPCache4j](https://github.com/httpcache4j/httpcache4j) implements a client-side cache that claims to implement the features expected of a HTTP 1.1 client cache. It might be worth checking out despite being a new project.

Disk stores do not seem to be implemented using human readable files - they involve serialized copies of HTTP resources, but I might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this](https://github.com/sogeti/DroidNetworking). Built on top of the Apache Http Client, it has support for response caching, authentication, HTTP and HTTPS and many other features.